# Business layer handling Linq-objects without knowing it?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I am refactoring my application to be less dependent on the data source (at the moment I am using Linq To Sql). But I like the nice way that Linq To Sql generates my classes out of my database and the way it tracks changes.

If this was not Linq I would just wrap the class with an interface and then let my business layer depend on that interface. However, I cannot do this with linq.

So lets say I have a repository `IFooRepository` where `Foos` is a table in the database and Linq has generated the class `Foo` for me. If I wouldn't bother about dependencies I would just return the linq object `Foo`. But my Business Logic layer has no clue of my Linq layer so I cannot inject those objects into my BLL. And as my Linq objects cannot implement any interface I cannot have any functions in the IFooRepository returning an `IFoo` implementation.

So, what I want is just for my BLL to handle the Linq objects but without knowing it so that my Linq Layer will track the changes of the BLL. Is this possible? I am thinking of just having a class inherit from the Linq object and then use that for passing around. Would that be valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your LINQ-to-SQL entities can implement interfaces, and you can add any functionality to them that you like. The generated entities are `partial` classes, so you can do something akin to this in another file, as long as it's part of your LINQ-to-SQL assembly:

```
public partial class YourEntityType : IInterfaceName
{
    // your implementation
}
```

You just need to define the contracts in another assembly that is referenced both by the LINQ-to-SQL assembly and the business logic assembly.

Comment: Yes, entities can implement an interface. But how will you get LINQ query support to work?

Comment: @Steven: I'm not sure what you're asking; interface implementation won't affect the ability to compose a query. The OP's thought was that because his entities cannot implement a custom interface, he cannot use a repository. Since this isn't the case, I think this addresses the question.

Comment: @Adam: The OP wants to be able to use those object in LINQ queries. Of course you can still run in memory LINQ (to objects) queries over those objects. However, LINQ to SQL has simply no clue what to do when you query an `IQueryable<IInterfaceName>`. That will simply not work. You need to work with the `YourEntityType` in the BLL to be able to do complex LINQ queries (that run inside the database).

Comment: @Steven: The OP never said anything about requiring the ability to query, nor does it seem to be to be a reasonable assumption that he expected it.

Comment: @Adam: I'm reading between the lines here, but indeed, he didn't explicitly said he wanted that.

Comment: @Steven: My assumption that he didn't need it is coming from the fact that he is trying to use a repository pattern, which typically exposes functions to obtain an entity (or collection thereof), rather than allowing the consuming code to specify a query itself. In other words, his repository would expose functions like `GetFoosByCustomer(string customerId)` or something similar.

Comment: @Adam: When you look at the repository pattern from Martin Fowler (http://bit.ly/19cpyX) you see that it may except a `Criteria` object, which allows the repository to do efficient filtering. In Fowler’s pattern, the consumer specifies the query by creating a set of `Criteria` objects. This is, in fact, exactly what we do when using  `IQueryable`. The consumer specifies the LINQ query (=criteria) and the LINQ provider  (=mapper) executes it inside the database.  In other words, it is perfectly fine for the repository to expose an `IQueryable`, since that’s the intend of the original pattern.

Answer (score 1):

This is certainly possible, especially with LINQ to SQL. You need to do two things here:

1. Use [POCO objects](http://www.thinqlinq.com/default/LINQ-to-SQL-support-for-POCO.aspx) (see [here](http://blog.tonysneed.com/2009/01/16/t4-poco-templates-for-l2s-and-ef/) and [here](https://l2st4.codeplex.com/) for T4 automation).
2. Hide the `DataContext` [behind an abstraction](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=84).

Good luck.